# Hierarchical Linking in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker

I want to link three files but in hierarchical way.

```
// a.c
int fun1(){...}
int fun2(){...}

// b.c
extern int parameter;
int fun3(){...//using parameter here}

// main.c
int parameter = 1;
int main(){...// use fun1 fun2 fun3}
```

So, I first compile three files separately into object file `a.o`, `b.o` and `main.o`. And then I want to combine `a.o` and `b.o` into another object file `tools.o`. And eventually use `tools.o` and `main.o` to generate executable file.

But, when I try to combine `a.o` and `b.o` like `ld -o tools.o a.o b.o`, the linker says `undefined reference to 'parameter'`. How could I link those object files into an intermediate object file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `-r` option to produce a relocatable object file (think 'reusable'):

```
ld -o tools.o -r a.o b.o
```

---

### Working code

#### abmain.h

```
extern void fun1(void);
extern void fun2(void);
extern void fun3(void);
extern int parameter;
```

#### a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abmain.h"
void fun1(void){printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void fun2(void){printf("%s\n", __func__);}
```

#### b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abmain.h"
void fun3(void){printf("%s (%d)\n", __func__, ++parameter);}
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abmain.h"

int parameter = 1;
int main(void){fun1();fun3();fun2();fun3();return 0;}
```

#### Compilation and execution

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c a.c
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c b.c
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c main.c
$ ld -r -o tools.o a.o b.o
$ gcc -o abmain main.o tools.o
$ ./abmain
fun1
fun3 (2)
fun2
fun3 (3)
$
```

Proved on Mac OS X 10.11.6 with GCC 6.1.0 (and the XCode 7.3.0 loader, etc).  However, the `-r` option has been in the `ld` command on mainstream Unix since at least the [7th Edition Unix](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/) (circa 1978), so it is likely to be available with most Unix-based compilation systems, even if it is one of the more widely unused options.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I want.